# Looking for help writing python code for Raspberry pi to make an interactive old school phone

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, gpio

I am an absolute N00b when it comes to Python and I have no idea how to turn my 'sudo'- code into actual code.I'm also having issues with the GPIO pins in my pi.

I would very much like some help coding this project.

I've tried making separate codes to test the GPIO pins but they never seem to work properly, I'm not using any resistors and I probably should even though I have no idea which ones and where.

I have tried to use the Bluetooth speaker with my pi but it always seems to prefer the HDMI even though I try to force it to Bluetooth, it just won't go.

I have been learning python in my free time as much as I can but since I am a full-time student, I haven't been able to learn very much and my knowledge of c++ has been entirely useless so far.

This is my sudo code

```
loop(called while on)
  if(handset is on the cradle)
    Do nothing and loop “while on” again
  else
    Clear Code
    loop(called dialing loop)
      If (time<3seconds)
        Play dialtone.mp3
        if(number indicator is off)
          Stop playing dialtone.mp3
          Reset time
          Count number of pulses from #pulser
          Assign number to the next letter of Code
          Exit to dialing loop
        Else
          Start counting time
          Exit to dialing loop
      Else
        Search thumbstick for Code.mp3
        if (Code.mp3 exists)
          Play Code.mp3
          Exit to while on loop
        Else
          Play dropped call.mp3 for 3 seconds
          Exit to dialing loop
```

My goal is to use an old rotary phone with a raspberry pi that will let you dial a number (arbitrary length) an audio file associated with that number (one file per number-one number per file) will be played through the handset. My restrictions are: the files and codes must be read from a thumb drive, there must not be a cap on the number of files, there must not be a cap on the length of the number you can dial, all the outward facing parts of the phone must look like the original phone, it must be a raspberry pi. the dial on the phone uses two leaf switches, one that pulses an amount of times based on the number that is dialed and one that is active until a user starts to dial a number. There is a needle switch attached to the cradle that will detect whether or not the handset is on the cradle and the audio is being played through a Bluetooth speaker.

Answer (score 0):

You could always start here: https://leanpub.com/RPiMRE

You can read it online for free: Here's a section on GPIO:
https://leanpub.com/RPiMRE/read#leanpub-auto-pin-header-1

Again it's free and a good resource with code examples on how to map what you're looking to do for your project.  It might not be straight away what you're looking for but might have some bits that can help you.  Good Luck!

Comment: Do you want to use a real rotary phone or just simulate one? For the real handset you will need to boost the voltage. If your want to build the dialer yourself you will have a few difficulties. As a mechanical device it is not so simple... If you just want to simulate the looks and feels... Find an old scroll wheel mouse and disassemble it. The scroll wheel could be the dialer, and the hook cold be the moose button. Then connect the 3.5mm to the headset's speaker. Or if your shop around you might find a cheap old exchange modem that can service team phones...

Comment: I'm using a real old phone, how would I go about bosting the voltage?